# MessageBoxManager does not exist in Current Context error

Tags: c#, messagebox

I get the compile error message "MessageBoxManager does not exist in current context from project SetTags when I try to start a project contained within a solution that with a different project as the Startup Project. Within SetTags.cs the lines containing MessageBoxManager have a wavy blue line beneath the MessageBoxManager string, which is coloured turquoise. Hovering over it shows the message "The type or namespace MessageBoxManager does not appear in the namespace 'System.Windows.Forms' (are you missing an assembly reference)?.
There is a reference to System.Windows.Forms (located in file C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Windows.Forms.dll) in project SetTags, and the statement using System.Windows.Forms. There is a reference to System.Windows.Form in another project in the solution pointing to the same file. There is no compile error in this project.

Cleaning the solution removes the blue wavy line from the MessageBoxManager reference but if I try to start the solution compile errors appear and the blue wavy lines re-appear beneath the references to MessageBoxManager in SetTags.

I am using VS2013 on Win 10, .Net45. Project SetTags is built for AnyCPU

Answer (score 0):

Tried removing and then re-adding System.Windows.Form reference to SetTags and this seems to fix the problem.

Comment: This is weird, that class is not defined in the System.Windows.Form dll.

Comment: You're quite right - I have an external ref to MessageBoxManager.dll, which I got from Code Project https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13123/MessageBoxManager-A-Windows-Forms-component-that-p